# Using std::erf in device code

Tags: cuda, std

When I use std::erf in device code with a floating point like so

```
float r = std::erf(0.1f);
```

I get the  the error

```
calling a constexpr __host__ function("erfc") from a __device__ function is not allowed.
```

while

```
double r = std::erf(0.1);
```

or

```
float r = erff(0.1f);
```

Seem to work. Is this a missing implementation?

Comment: You're saying "host  code" but this error is arising from the use in a `__device__` function which is device code.  Which is it?

Comment: Ah sorry. I did mean device code. Corrected

Comment: In device code, the supported `float` implementations are listed [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE) and the supported `double` implementations are listed [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE).  `erf` in the CUDA device math api is indeed available in `double` but not `float`

Comment: Mmm.. `erff` seems supported CUDA device math api, but I guess it is not implemented in the C++ API.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: So, the CUDA math API does indeed have both `erf`  and `erff`. So what gives?...

Comment: I'm not able to parse your question "what gives?". Since the `float` `erf` is **not available** in the CUDA math API, it appears to me that the compiler is attempting to use the host (library) function, which is illegal in device code. It may very well be that the host library observes that `erf(SOME_FLOAT_CONSTANT)` can be implemented via some `constexpr` involving the host `erfc` function. It is still illegal in device code.  When the original source line is changed to use `double` throughout, it compiles. It doesn't surprise me, and I don't know what you are confused about, or what "gives".

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But the pages you linked to suggest that it is available... see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1g3b8115ff34a107f4608152fd943dbf81).

Comment: `erff` is available in device code. `erf` for `float` is not. OP already pointed out that `erff` works. And using `std::` in device code is sketchy anyway

Comment: @RobertCrovella Something doesn't add up. `erf(float)` in device code should compile and it does for me (CUDA 8):`#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void dummy()
{
    float r = erf(0.1f);
    printf("Result of erf is (as double) %lf\n", (double) r);
}

int main (void)
{
    dummy<<<1,1>>>();
    return 0;
}
` I am not aware that `std::[any math function]` is supported in device code, however.

Comment: @Tohiko Could you point to the place in the CUDA documentation where it says that namespace `std` is supported in device code? In my current understanding, there is no such support, so errors would be expected. In device code, you can simply invoke `erf(float)` or `erff(float)`.

Comment: @Robert Crovella, why would using `std::erf` be sketchy? As far as I understand it would call the underlying `erf` or `erff` based on the input parameter type. Not sure why it's not doing that here though.

Comment: Because, officially, `std::` is [not supported in device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-library).  The simple answer here is to not use `std::` in device code, and simply choose your math functions directly from the supported library documentation, which I have already linked.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer, but a challenge of your premise. `float r = erff(0.1f);` doesn't quite work. That is, it compiles, but you don't get just an immediate value computed at compile time. I compiled this:

```
__global__ void dummy()
{
    double r = std::erf(0.1);
    printf("Result of erf is (as double) %lf\n", (double) r);
}
```

and in the resulting PTX, I find that compiles into 333 lines of code (including comments, empty lines and .loc instructions; I'm sparing you the sordid (details);  That's *not* what you would expect. With the CUDA'ish `erff()`

```
__global__ void dummy()
{
    float r = erff(0.1f);
    printf("Result of erf is (as double) %lf\n", (double) r);
}
```

you get about 20 lines, 12 or so actual instructions. Still not a constexpr computation in my book.

Comment: @njuffa: Sorry, I mis-copy-pasted.